# How to define an action of an algebra on a set?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $ \Omega = \left(n_i\right)_{i \in  \mathbb{N}}$ be a collection of nonnegative integers. An $\Omega$-algebra on $X$ is a pair $\left(X, \left(w_i\right)_{i \in\mathbb{N}}\right)$ where for all $i \in I$; 
$$
w_i:X^{n_i}\longrightarrow X
$$
is a $n_i$ ary operation. 
Now, my question is how one defines the action of an $\Omega$-algebra on a given set, along the line of [how we define the action of a group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Definition) on a set.

Comment: It is not clear to me that $\Omega$-algebras ought to act on sets at all.

Comment: @Hooman Could you give more background/context?

Comment: As far as I can see you need additional operations on the collection of endomorphisms of your sets. So perhaps if you passed from Sets to some enriched category? I can't say I can think of any interesting example of such a structure though, and it seems quite asymmetric. I'm wondering if the notion of a group action shouldn't be considered more of a construction on sets than on groups, arising due to the existence of a canonical group structure on the set of automorphisms of a set (or more generally the objects of a category).

Comment: @DylanMoreland I was trying to appreciate the concept of Operads at Wiki. I came upon this "Algebras are to operads as group representations are to group" and somehow I found my self asking the above question.